# Selenium: ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_list[proxytumb])

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    driver.get(url="https://lzt.market")
```

> ! Message: unknown error: net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED
> (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.76)

I don't know what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your proxy doesn't work. Check the following:

- Does the proxy require authentification? Authentificated proxies aren't supported for chrome by default.
- check, if your proxy is good. You can do that, for example by using `curl -x "http://user:password@proxy_host:port" "http://httpbin.org/ip"` or `curl -x "http://user:password@proxy_host:port" "http://httpbin.org/ip"`.

Comment: the proxies were bad, thanks for the help

Comment: If my answer answers your question, pleas mark it as THE ANSWER.