# How to hidden web site for scraping?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web

## I am interested in scraping using selenium library.

Hello, everybody.
Thank you for considering my first question.
I hope your kind response.
When I am scraping using selenium, want to hidden work web site for other work.

```
#import library
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

# add argument for chrome browser
service = Service()
options = Options() 
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")

options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.yoox.com/jp/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9/shoponline?dept=newarrivalswomen&attributes={%27nwrrvls%27%3a[%27nwlstwk2%27]}")
time.sleep(1)
```

But the error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project\Crowdworks\11.24scraping\ShopScraping\scraping.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.get("https://www.yoox.com/jp/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9/shoponline?
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: net::ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED
  (Session info: headless chrome=119.0.6045.160)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF738F982B2+55298]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738F05E02]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DC05AB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DBC353]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DAF4CC]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DB0714]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DAF8DF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DAE803]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DAE7A8]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DACF0E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DAD803]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DC29BF]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738E3AE27]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738E220AA]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738E3AAA4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738E21E83]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DF670A]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738DF7964]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF739310AAB+3694587]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF73936728E+4048862]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF73935F173+4015811]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF7390347D6+695590]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738F10CE8]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738F0CF34]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738F0D062]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF738EFD3A3]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF907707614+20]
        RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF9078426A1+33]
```

I don't fix the bug.
**Please help me!**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium: ERR\_PROXY\_CONNECTION\_FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234370/selenium-err-proxy-connection-failed)

Answer (score 0):

This error is proxy error, and you want to hidden work web site for other work that is do not show webdriver: `options.add_argument('--headless')` but it should be from that `from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions`  and options should be`options = ChromeOptions()`

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='webdriver/chromedriver_windows_115.exe')
options = ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument("--ignore-ssl-errors")

options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.yoox.com/jp/%E3%83%AC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9/shoponline?dept=newarrivalswomen&attributes={%27nwrrvls%27%3a[%27nwlstwk2%27]}")
print(driver.page_source)
```

[image]

if if you use options.add_argument("--headless")
[image]

try to use `options.add_argument("--headless=new")`
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your kind response.
But it still doesn't work.

Here is error code:
```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=53895): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/da16af0113f901b42baad59cc4cf0d7d/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000018ACECE9910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Comment: In my opinion, Some operations such as click(), send_key() might be performed by showing web site screen, not hidden.
Waiting your answer...

Comment: I am not sure that you used linux or windows and please try to designate  executable_path. Please give permission to webdriver if you use linux.

Comment: and I do not know your selenium version.

Comment: Thank you. 
I use windows 10, and selenium version is 4.15.2
I'm waiting for your reply.

Comment: I fix my answer, please check it.it will result in failure to obtain the complete html content.

Comment: `service = Service(executable_path='webdriver/chromedriver_windows_115.exe')`
It doesn't work well.
Could you explain more detail.

Comment: it is path of your webdriver.

Comment: Thank you sir.
It works well. But when screen hidden, selenium doesn't read element in html.
the error follows:

Comment: ```
print(driver.page_source)
 <html><head></head><body></body></html>
```
there is nothing in <body> tag.
How can I handle it?

Comment: Currently there are only do not use the headless mode...[Selenium Headless Chrome empty page source (not UA issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77585943/selenium-headless-chrome-empty-page-source-not-ua-issue?noredirect=1#comment136801092_77585943)

Comment: So you mean there is no way?

Comment: For now, yep. Using options.add_argument("--headless")

Comment: A solution has been found, please use: `options.add_argument("--headless=new")`

Comment: **Thank you for your response**. It's good for hidden.
But code doesn't work, it still occurs error.

Comment: What went wrong? I have updated my answer and please check it.  I can access it successfully while hiding.