# Selenium Headless Chrome empty page source (not UA issue)

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

so I am trying to open some pages with selenium Chrome, and everything works fine while headless mode isn't used. But when I use headless mode, the page source returns

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Searched for something that'd help, but to no avail. I tried adding User Agent as most of the forums suggest, but it didn't help. Neither did using a bunch of other options (such as `--allow-insecure-localhost`)

Tried looking for answers in similar questions, but none helped. Also tried a bunch of chrome options.

Comment: Is it possible to try sandbox mode or add waiting.

Comment: I had tried both of these, and neither helped... The only thing that helps is if I do not use the headless mode...

Comment: Yes, I found it, and I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: But, I think it related to User-Agent and JavaScript.

Comment: Dont forget to enable logging  incase there are any error messages or warnings that might provide more useful information.                                                   
                                                          
options.add_argument("--enable-logging")
options.add_argument("--v=1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the answer, thanks to [dhruv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16891669/dhruv)'s answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77081435/14829049

The answer is to use `--headless=new` instead of `--headless`

So technically, the `--headless` is actually a separate chrome implementation, not a mode of operation; While the new `--headless=new` uses the same chrome as in the headfull mode. In case anyone would like to read a bit more about it: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Comment: you are wonderful.